# torctl errors out with; TorCtl.connect() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, tor

I have downloaded the latest `tor-nodes.py` and the latest `pytorctl`.

I've installed `pytorctl` with Python's `setup.py build` and then `python setup.py install`;
there where no errors.

But now when I run `./tor-nodes.py` I get an error:

```
# ./tor-nodes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tor-nodes.py", line 11, in <module>
    conn = TorCtl.connect()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an issue with your import statement. If you have...

```
import TorCtl
```

... then try replacing that with...

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
```

All this said, you might want to look into [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/). TorCtl was [deprecated in December, 2012](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/torctl-deprecation-and-stem-plans) in favour of Stem.

Cheers! -Damian